# Ebay user name change shows no error message

Tags: ebay

I just registered on Ebay and it generated a very useless user name.

So there is an option that you can change that user name: https://reg.ebay.com/reg/ChangeUserName

When I enter a basic name, I get a *somewhat* useful error (there are no alternatives at "below"):

[image]

When I enter some other name, I get another message:

[image]

When I enter some unique name, I get an exclamation mark...and **no error message**.

[image]

What does it mean? How should I know what to correct? This looks very lame...

Comment: Looks like an obvious bug. Log in and report.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have done it, waiting for confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to wait 30 days **after registration** as well, so I need to try it then again.

The empty error message is not a bug according to eBay technical support: *"..when you have several attempts to redo a process, you will only be re-routed to the page or stuck in a loop without any message. This may be what happened when you got the empty error message."*